# Congruences with exponents

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

I'd like a clarification for this exercise.

$$ 7^x \equiv 19\mod30$$

He says: ''the $19$ has to be written like a power of $7$ otherwise it wouldn't be solvable.''

So he writes

$$ 7^x \equiv 7^2\mod30$$

*First question:* Why do I have to write $19$ as a power of $7$? And why $7^2$ and not $7^5$ ?

Then he proceeds by writing

\begin{align} 7^x-2 &\equiv 1\mod30\\
y&=x-2 \\
7^y &\equiv 1\mod30\\
x-2 &\equiv 0\mod30\\
y &\equiv 0\mod4\end{align}

What is the reasoning in general about this procedure? What am I looking for when solving this type of exercise?

Comment: We need to have $7^2$ and not $7^5$ because $7^5\equiv 7\not\equiv 19\pmod{30}$, while $7^2 = 49\equiv 19$. And you have to write $19$ as a power of $7$, because that's what $7^x\equiv 19$ _asks_ about. It literally says "Seven to the power of what is congruent to $19$?"

Answer (score 0):

As $30\equiv2\cdot3\cdot5$

$$7^x\equiv19\pmod{30}\implies7^x\equiv19\pmod2\iff1^x\equiv1$$ which holds true for all integer $x$

Similarly for $\pmod3$  the condition holds true for all integer $x$

$$7^x\equiv19\pmod{30}\implies7^x\equiv19\pmod5$$

$$\iff2^x\equiv4\equiv2^2\implies x\equiv2\pmod{\phi(5)}$$

Comment: Didn't understand the $ 1^x $ $ \equiv 1 $ part or the other... i understood that since 30 is a composite number of prime factors, then the numbers have to be all congruent in mod 2,3 and 5. But still, why not $7^3$?

Comment: @InfoB, Why $$7^3?$$

Comment: Why not? What would change?

Comment: @InfoB, Please share your steps

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since $7^2 = 49 = 19 ~\mbox{mod}~ 30$ (The remainder when dividing 49 by 30), so we can replace 19 by $7^2$.
So that $$7^x \equiv 7^2~\mbox{mod}~ 30 $$
dividing by $7^2$, we get
$$7^{(x-2)} \equiv 1~\mbox{mod}~ 30 $$
Let $y = x- 2$, then 
$$7^y \equiv 1~\mbox{mod}~ 30 $$
So that $y = x-2 \equiv 0 ~\mbox{mod}~ 30$ (As the way of dealing with normal power).

Comment: Now i know from where that $7^2$! Thanks to everyone!